# SetState inside map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state

I should check if value of the object is empty and setstate but the problem is that my data is object and im looping through for checking if value is false or true. I know that I cant setstate inside map but cant find a good way to do that. Im using hooks

Comment: What is the stateful variable you need to update?

Comment: const [send, setSend] = useState(true);

I want to save the boolean inside ex. send variable, if the check value is false set send value to false if not true

Answer (score 2):

To tweak your code, just add `setSend(isAllowed)` after. But it'd be more appropriate to use `.some`:

```
setSend(
  Object.values(data).some(
    dataItem => dataItem.items.some(
      item => item.check === false
    )
  )
);
```

Comment: I think `Object.values(data)` would be an array of objects with key `items` wouldn't it?

Comment: yes Object.values(data) is returing array of my items

Comment: it doesnt work . Unhandled Rejection (Error): Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

Comment: @Narine Can you post the full code? When do you want the `send` variable to get updated after the component mounts, or do you just want it to get set once?

Comment: I put it inside button click now its not re-render but its not propely changing state, now i have 3false that mean that 3items.check is true, 2 true but it is always staying true. I newwd to say that if one of the item.check is false set state to false

Comment: @Narine Please post your full code - it's quite unclear at the moment what exactly you're trying to do without seeing the code.